# Solr and eXist-db integration

Tags: xml, xpath, solr, exist-db

We have XML files stored in an [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/exist/) XML database that are needed to be indexed and stored in [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). The documentation does not mention eXist much. If someone here knows, please help. Much appreciated!

Comment: An almost identical question was just asked in the XML and Related Technologies Network group on Linkedin:  http://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=100978256&gid=71299.  If that doesn't answer your questions, I'd welcome you to join the exist-open  mailing list and send a more specific description of your requirements.  More eXist-db users are on exist-open than here, so that's your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Solr's [URLDataSource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2BAC8-HTTP_Datasource) to access eXist-db using REST.
So instead of pushing data to Solr, you use Solr's DataImportHandler to read the data from eXist and mold it as it's going in with [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor).

How to GET xml resources from eXist:
http://exist-db.org/exist/devguide_rest.xml

Comment: Thanks for answering. The REST interface works but we can't get XPathEntityProcessor to produce multiple documents when it is nested. We had the parent XPathEntityProcessor to work on the eXist-DB collection. The child XPathEntityProcessor works on the individual XML files.

Comment: If you cannot get any of the available entity processors to work with your data, maybe you should consider [writing your own](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#EntityProcessor) by extending [EntityProcessorBase](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/EntityProcessorBase.html) and overriding nextRow() method.

Comment: Or, even better in your case, by extending [XPathEntityProcessor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/XPathEntityProcessor.html).

Answer (score 0):

We've done something similar but not from eXist DB. You have a couple of options, you can:

- transform the XML that is outputted from your DB into the [XML format that SOLR likes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) to consume using XSTL
- write a script to output [CSV](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV) (or [JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON)) from your DB and import into SOLR
- assuming there is a JDBC driver for eXist DB, use the SOLR [data import handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_RDBMS)